# How to perform segue when tapping a UIButton inside a XIB file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

[image]

I have a `XIB` file (Right side of the image) with a button inside. Then added the `XIB` file (or `UIView`) to the Shop View controller (Far left side, red box).

I need to press the button inside the `XIB` file so that I can perform a segue from the Shop VC to the other VC (Middle VC on the image).

Any method of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Call this method in Shop VC when button is clicked

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueId", sender: nil)
```

Comment: That's the thing. I can't drag the button to the Shop VC since the button is in this UIView

Comment: @RenzTan, you can link 2 view controllers without being by the button itself.